# Log every request to an Amazon Linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, logging

We run a simple server using a Linux EC2 instance, which includes a Java applet with a .JAR and associated assets .ZIP file. We're seeing some issues on the client side which suggest the applet is trying to access files from the ZIP directly on the server, e.g http://our-site.com/resources/graphics/sprite.png instead of assets.zip/resources/graphics/sprite.png. But we are not sure if these requests are happening or are just being logged and internally get mapped to the ZIP.

So I need a way on the server to log all file requests received. It seems like a normal kind of thing to do but I'm a developer not a sysadmin so I don't have a clue if this is something I can just turn on, or need to do myself, and what I should be searching for online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access log should show all `http://our-site.com` requests.

It is likely that the applet is trying to access resources from your server.  This is the default classloader behaviour.  If the ZIP is on the classpath of the JAR, files will be loaded from it if the web access fails.  There is a way to change this behavior, but I have not dealt with this problem for a few years.

Comment: It was indeed the access log, trusty `tail` to the rescue. And thanks very much for the applet advice, I wasn't expecting any help on the specifics!